# Independency vs ignorance - why is conditioning on a variable interpreted as ignoring the other one? (partial dependency plots)

Tags: machine-learning, interpretation, expected-value, independence, conditional-expectation

#### Setting

Let $f(X)=f(X_S, X_C)$ be an estimator of $y$ using random variables (or random vectors) $X_S$ and $X_C$. The authors (see below) mention that:
$$ \tilde{f}_S (X_S) = \mathrm{E}( f(X_S, X_C) | X_S) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(X_S,X_C)p(X_C|X_S)dX_c $$
is the the effect of $X_S$ on $f(X)$ ignoring the effects of $X_C$. $p(X_C|X_S)$ is the conditional PDF of $X_C$ and $p(X_C)$ the marginal one. The authors also mention that the partial dependency function:

$$\bar{f}_S (X_S)= \mathrm{E}_{X_C} \, f(X_S, X_C) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(X_S,X_C)p(X_C)dX_c$$

is not ignoring the effects of $X_C$

#### Question

Why can conditioning be interpreted as ignorance, since $\tilde f$ still depends on $X_C$ through $p(X_C|X_S)$ which can be different for every value of $X_S$? What is the difference between the terms "ignorance" and "dependency"? If ignorance means simply integrating the variable it out, i.e. letting it only play a constant or multiplicative role for all values of the other variable, why is $\bar f$ also not considered as ignoring $X_C$, since that's what it leads to? In other words, why is marginal expectancy not ignorance while conditional is?

---

#### References:

From Hastie, Tibshirani & Friedman (Elements of Statistical Learning, 2nd ed) and Friedman 1999 (Greedy Function Approximation: A gradient boosting machine) in the context of partial dependency plots, i.e. black-box model interpretation.

[PDP - Hastie, Tibshirani & Friedman (Elements of Statistical Learning, 2nd ed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpC6G.png)

[Difference between averaging and ignoring the partial dependencies?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385008/difference-between-averaging-and-ignoring-the-partial-dependencies) (Question contains the term ignoring, but focuses on mathematical side; I am more interested in the intuition and terminology.)

Comment: I agree that this subsection in ESL is extremely confusing. It seems to me that it is $\tilde{f}_S(X_S)$ which is NOT ignoring the interactions between $X_S$ and $X_C$ since $p(X_C | X_S)$ would change with a change in $X_S$. So I suspect the terminology might be mixed up in this subsection.